# â€“ encoding of em dash when inserted using CSS :after

Tags: css, encoding, character-encoding

I'm getting the old `â€“` on my page when I try to render an em dash ( `—` ). This can be cleared up by adding `<meta charset="utf-8">` to the document head, I believe. But in this case I'm inserting the em dash via css.

```
.el:after{
   content: "— content to be after";
}
```

Somehow it is not being encoded properly. `content: "&mdash;";` does not work either; it only renders the amersand code. How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to save the file in the same format that you claim it is.

Comment: @Dave I'm sorry, what?

Comment: You might also try `content: "\2014  content to be after";`

Comment: @thomas claiming a charset of utf-8 will only work if your file is actually utf-8. Your text editor may be saving it in a different encoding. Anyway, see my answer for an easy way around all the encoding pitfalls. Setting the encoding in the CSS file as others have suggested may not help here, because from `â€“`, it looks like your file is *not* utf-8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While setting the correct encoding is always a good thing to do, I try to avoid this situation entirely and use only ASCII characters in HTML, JavaScript and CSS:

```
content:"\2014"
```

Unicode characters are represented by `\hexValue` in CSS.

Beware that if the following character is `0-9` or `a-f` (or `A-F`), it will be considered part of the unicode character. You can put a space after it: `"\2014 stuff"`, and the space won't be displayed (it just marks the end of the character). To actually put a space after it, use two spaces.

Comment: Here is a fiddle based on your answer http://jsfiddle.net/yTM5d/ Works perfectly.

Comment: wow. this is very cool. thank you. Why do you think it is better than using other encodings?

Comment: because it's very easy to accidentally save in the wrong encoding, or have some process automatically convert it. But the ASCII character set is identical in utf-8, meaning this will rarely fail (and if it does, all of your regular content will fail with it so you've got bigger problems!)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the following on top of your stylesheet

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

Your HTTP server (Apache, Nginx, etc) probably is specifying a different charset. It should be responding with:

```
Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8
```

For for info see [http://www.w3.org/](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset.en.php)

Comment: Literally, two seconds away from suggesting the same thing.